# Why is my main UIViewController being created twice?

Tags: ios, swift

I am following the HTCHHKR "Advanced iOS & Firebase: Rideshare" tutorial. There is a slideout menu,but mine is not working?

I have run the app through the debugger with breakpoints and the UIViewController HomeVC is being created twice. Not sure why this would be.

I noticed that his xcode project is older than my mine. He only has a AppDelegate and I have an AppDelegate and a SceneDelegate. His AppDelegate has a reference to `window?` but mine does NOT. I only have a reference to `window?` in SceneDelegate. So I added one myself, but this didn't fix the issue.

In ContainerVC he is manually launching the ViewControllers with the storyboard. I can see that this code is creating the leftsideVC and the HomeVC. But then HomeVC is getting instantiated again which looks like maybe its being created by the storyboard itself.

APPDELEGATE

```
    //
    //  AppDelegate.swift
    //  Hitcher
    //
    //  Created by J N on 12/25/19.
    //  Copyright © 2019 J N. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import Firebase

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        fileprivate var containerVC = ContainerVC()

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

            FirebaseApp.configure()

            containerVC = ContainerVC()
            window?.rootViewController = containerVC
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            return true
        }

        // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
            // Called when a new scene session is being created.
            // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
            return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
            // Called when the user discards a scene session.
            // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
            // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
        }


    }
```

HOMEVC

```
    //
    //  HomeVC.swift
    //  Hitcher
    //
    //  Created by J N on 12/27/19.
    //  Copyright © 2019 J N. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class HomeVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

        @IBAction func actionButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            actionButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: true, withMessage: nil)
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
        @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: RoundedShadowButton!

        @IBAction func centerMapBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            centerMapOnUserLocation()
        }

        @IBOutlet weak var destinationTextField: UITextField!
        var delegate: CenterVCDelegate?
        var manager: CLLocationManager?
        var regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000


        var tableView = UITableView()
        var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            manager = CLLocationManager()
            manager?.delegate = self
            manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

            checkLocationAuthStatus()

            mapView.delegate = self
            centerMapOnUserLocation()
            destinationTextField.delegate = self


        }

        func checkLocationAuthStatus() {
            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
                manager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            } else {
                manager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        }

        func centerMapOnUserLocation() {
            let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: mapView.userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
            mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

        }

        @IBAction func menuBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            delegate?.toggleLeftPanel()
        }


    }

    extension HomeVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
                mapView.showsUserLocation = true
                mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
            }
        }
    }

    extension HomeVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

            if textField == destinationTextField {
                tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: view.frame.height, width: view.frame.width - 40, height: view.frame.height - 170)
                tableView.layer.cornerRadius  = 5.0
                tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "locationCell")

                tableView.delegate = self
                tableView.dataSource = self



                tableView.tag = 18
                tableView.rowHeight = 60
                view.addSubview(tableView)
                animateTableView(shouldShow: true)
            }
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if textField == destinationTextField {
                // performSearch
                view.endEditing(true)
            }
            return true
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        }

        func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func animateTableView(shouldShow: Bool) {
            if shouldShow {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 210, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: self.view.frame.height - 170)
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: self.view.frame.height - 170)
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                    for subview in self.view.subviews {
                        if subview.tag == 18 {
                            subview.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    extension HomeVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            animateTableView(shouldShow: false)
            print("selected")
        }
    }
```

COTAINERVC

```
    //
    //  ContainerVC.swift
    //  Hitcher
    //
    //  Created by J N on 12/26/19.
    //  Copyright © 2019 J N. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import QuartzCore


    enum SlideOutState {
        case collapsed
        case leftPanelExpanded
    }

    enum ShowWhichVC {
        case homeVC
    }

    var showVC: ShowWhichVC = .homeVC

    class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

        var homeVC: HomeVC!
        var currentState: SlideOutState = .collapsed
        var leftVC: LeftSidePanelVC!
        var centerController: UIViewController!

        var isHidden = false
        let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 160
        var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            initCenter(screen: showVC)

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        func initCenter(screen: ShowWhichVC) {
            var presentingController: UIViewController

            showVC = screen

            if homeVC == nil {
                homeVC = UIStoryboard.homeVC()
                homeVC.delegate = self
            }

            presentingController = homeVC

            if let con = centerController {
                con.view.removeFromSuperview()
                con.removeFromParent()
            }
            centerController = presentingController

            view.addSubview(centerController.view)
            addChild(centerController)
            centerController.didMove(toParent: self)
        }

        override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
            return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
        }

        override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
            return isHidden
        }

    }

    extension ContainerVC: CenterVCDelegate {
        func toggleLeftPanel() {
            let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .leftPanelExpanded)
            if notAlreadyExpanded {
                addLeftPanelViewController()
            }
            animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)
        }

        func addLeftPanelViewController() {
            if leftVC == nil {
                leftVC = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
                addChildSidePanelViewController(leftVC!)
            }
        }

        func addChildSidePanelViewController(_ sidePanelController: LeftSidePanelVC) {
            view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, at: 0)
            addChildSidePanelViewController(sidePanelController)
            sidePanelController.didMove(toParent: self)
        }

        @objc func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: Bool) {
            if shouldExpand {
                isHidden = !isHidden
                animateStatusBar()

                setupWhiteCoverView()

                currentState = .leftPanelExpanded
                animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: centerController.view.frame.width - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
            } else {
                isHidden = !isHidden
                animateStatusBar()
                hideWhiteCoverView()
                animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { (finished) in
                    if finished == true {
                        self.currentState = .collapsed
                        self.leftVC = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGFloat, completion:((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut,
                           animations: {
                            self.centerController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
            }, completion: completion)
        }

        func setupWhiteCoverView(){
            let whiteCoverView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
            whiteCoverView.alpha = 0.0
            whiteCoverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            whiteCoverView.tag = 25

            self.centerController.view.addSubview(whiteCoverView)
            whiteCoverView.fadeTo(alphaValue: 0.75, withDuration: 0.2)

            tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand:)))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

            self.centerController.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }

        func hideWhiteCoverView() {
            centerController.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
            for subview in self.centerController.view.subviews {
                if subview.tag == 25 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        subview.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: {(finished) in
                        subview.removeFromSuperview()
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        func animateStatusBar(){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            })
        }
    }

    private extension UIStoryboard {
        class func mainStoryBoard()  -> UIStoryboard {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        }

        class func leftViewController() -> LeftSidePanelVC? {
            return mainStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(identifier: "LeftSidePanelVC") as? LeftSidePanelVC
        }

        class func homeVC() -> HomeVC? {
            return mainStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeVC") as? HomeVC
        }

    }
```

UPDATE:

Debugged again after fixing below kovpas suggestion. The viewDidLoad in HomeVC is being called twice. Once from ContainerVC code thread the other one has no thread so I guess it is being called by the Storyboard since it is the initial view shown?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `ContainerVC` twice in the AppDelegate:

```
    fileprivate var containerVC = ContainerVC()
    ...
    containerVC = ContainerVC()
```

Therefore `HomeVC` also gets created twice.

Comment: Removed the 2nd reference and still not working.  Line 65 of HomeVC, sliding menue button handler, when touched shows delegate? as nil.